# SharePoint Content Query Web Part question

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm using CQW to display announcement list. Only problem I'm facing to provide "Add new announcement" button like the one having in Announcement list.Here is my CQW ,
[image]

I've tried adding custom "Add new Announcement" link from SharePoint designer. But this solution looks ugly. Can we provide exact button and the interface which default "Add new announcement" link provides ? Please not it's on web part page.

Here is my SPD if someone want to see,
[image]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to add a link in your web part right? Editing the XSLT wont help you?

Comment: @Shoban,If I edit the XSLT, for example add HTML table & button then it will be repeated while parsing.I don't think so modifying XSL will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the XSLT can be your solution.
If the repeating is the only thing that stops you from modifying the XSLT, we have to solve that.

You can stop the repeating by using a check on the current position. Only add the link when the position is 1.
Define the current position and use it:

```
<xsl:param name="CurPos" />
<xsl:if test="$CurPos = 1">
  <![CDATA[ Here your link can be placed ]]>
</xsl:if>
```